# Shoulder pain, around the cuff. Any help?

Tags: shoulders, rotator-cuff

I have pain (not too bad) in the right shoulder.  Annoying pain.  I believe it could be rotator cuff related, and there is some soreness.  I have had a shoulder cuff injury there before but it cleared up.  This was years ago though and i've been fine since.  I have noticed the last6 months that after working out my upper half (shoulders and pecs) my right shoulder is a lot higher than the left.  It takes effort and time (about an hour) for them to level out again.  I am not sure why I let this go but there you go.

What does this indicate?

Also this is around the time I started squats.  Could it be squat related?  Nerves etc?

Oh and my right side has always been weaker than my left.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of exercises have you been doing for those six months? Specifically what movements, machines, db's, barbell's, etc.

Comment: Thanks guys, and I don't expect you to be able to diagnose fully. I do gym work, which is varied but includes shoulder work, and it's varied. It includes Smith machine, dumbbells, bar bell, only a tiny bit of machine. I also only go 3 times a week at most. Problem also is my work. As a delivery driver I lift a lot of weight (a lot), and drive a fair bit. I had an injury to the shoulder 5 years ago which was the same as now. It cleared up and since then I've done far more exercise and physical work, and I'm bigger and stronger, so I thought I'd conquered it. I never knew what the injury was the

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no real way for us to diagnose pain over the internet, especially in a joint as loosely structured as the shoulder. Could be the SITS muscles, ligaments, nerve impingement, etc etc. Best thing is to see a decent ortho.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no way for any of us to diagnose what's wrong.  However, as someone who has had a surgical repair of the rotator cuff, I might be able to provide some insight into what you're experiencing.  The rotator cuff is a somewhat complicated bundle of four muscles, tendons and ligaments, of which any one, can be injured.  And, I don't think performing squats would cause it.  Weakness may indicate nerve involvement.  One thing I would suggest is to grab a handheld mirror and position yourself with your back facing a larger wall mirror.  Take a look at your upper back in the handheld mirror.  Do you see anything out of the ordinary?  Do you notice any atrophy? Particularly around the shoulder blade? If you answered yes, I'd have the shoulder evaluated.

Comment: "There's no way to diagnose, but here's some diagnosis tips." -1.

Comment: @JohnP Funny, as I wrote that, I knew someone would interpret it from that context. My only desire was to impart some of the experiences I've had having to deal with such an issue.  That injury can be very tough to deal with mentally and physically.

Comment: @rrirower upvoted (back to 0). "off topic" or not, I think offering thoughtful feedback in the right direction is helpful, and we could use more helpful people around here.